# RTABMAP non-overlapping 3D cloud

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using rtabmap using stereo on a robot. Everything seems to work fine, except that the MapCloud does not contain registered clouds. The individual 3D maps (from different graph nodes) "supposedly" are not registered to each other. For example there are multiple (3 or 4) replica of the same scene which are not registered. Here are some details.

- ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04
- rectified/synchronized stereo being published at 15Hz
- odometry available (approx_sync, enabled when using wheel odometry)
- rtabmap database:
  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vtp0xao60fbfg33/AADkBI-FDUYuz6F6L-YC79nca?dl=0
- launch file
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiumj3fzs7bdbfj/tis_stereo_mapping.launch?dl=0

Please help, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267915/rtabmap-non-overlapping-3d-cloud/) by [lealem](https://answers.ros.org/users/28279/lealem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-08-03**:
Could you give us details on how you launched RTABMap, what ROS topics you're having difficulties with, the result of view_frames ?

**Comment by [lealem](https://answers.ros.org/users/28279/lealem/) on 2017-08-03**:
I would say the problem is with the cloud data (mapping result), everything else seems to work perfect! And I am launching using the "stereo_mapping.launch" file, with minor modifications (like topic names etc)
ps. all the demos work as expected

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-08-03**:
If you can share the resulting database (dropbox or google drive link), it can be useful.

**Comment by [lealem](https://answers.ros.org/users/28279/lealem/) on 2017-08-03**:
here is a link to the launch file i used and the rtabmap database
database https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vtp0xao60fbfg33/AADkBI-FDUYuz6F6L-YC79nca?dl=0
launch file https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiumj3fzs7bdbfj/tis_stereo_mapping.launch?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi lealem,

At first view the optimized trajectory after loop closure looks good:
[image: image description]

For the 3D map, there are indeed some problems with the 3D projection. I noticed that the scale of some point clouds are not the same, which would be caused by a poor synchronization between the left and right frames, in particular when the robot is rotating. Here two examples of frames taken before and after rotating at the same place:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

In first screenshot the far wall is about ~10/11 meters from the robot, as in the second screenshot the far wall is about ~5-6 meters from the robot. When rotating, as left and right frames are not synchronized, the disparity changes, making objects appearing more closer. With stereo, it is strongly recommend to use exactly synchronized cameras (e.g., hardware synchronization between left and right cameras), then with rtabmap use `approx_sync` parameter set to `false`.

PS: To get the 2D grid map as above, I used parameters: `Grid/MaxObstacleHeight=2`, `Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius=0.15`, `Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors=10`, `Grid/NormalsSegmentation=false`, `Grid/3D=false` and `Grid/ProjRayTracing=true`.

EDIT: just noticed that you were using `approx_sync` because of wheel odometry. To use `approx_sync=false` with wheel odometry, set `odom_frame_id` so that rtabmap uses TF to get odometry instead of the topic (for which `approx_sync` should be true).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lealem](https://answers.ros.org/users/28279/lealem/) on 2017-08-16**:
Hi Mathieu,
Thank you for the insight. Changed my stereo setup to the "ZED" and works like a charm!

Best,
Lealem